# Promises .then() with one argument

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, q

I am having trouble interpreting what the Promises/A+ spec meant by this...

https://promisesaplus.com/#point-23

If you have a promise and call .then with one argument, does that mean that the single argument will be called regardless of success or failure?

I feel like it could go either way with interpreting this.  I guess the library I would be most concerned with is Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to a `.then()` handler, whether it is the only argument or not, is always the fulfilled handler and is only called if the promise is fulfilled.  That first argument is not treated differently if there is or is not a second argument passed.

Answer (score 2):

So to anyone who is  unsure, I made a test script that you can run in your node REPL.  The definitive answer is that no it will not call the success with an err attachment.

```
var Q = require('q');

//call with whether or not the promise will resolve
function aPromise (bool) {
    var def = Q.defer();
    if (!bool) {
        def.reject("oooo0o0o00o0 rejected");
    }
    def.resolve('winner winner chicken dinner');
    return def.promise
}

var whatGonnaBe = aPromise(false)

//The Example
whatGonnaBe
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('1')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + '1');
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('2')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + '2');
},
function (response) {
    console.log('3')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response) + '3');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the first argument is always the "success" or "resolved" argument.  The second argument is always the failure argument, and you can omit it when chaining promises together and have a single "fail" argument to handle all fails.  This code is just conceptual:

```
promise1.then(function() {
    return promise2;
}).then(function() {
    return promise3;
}).then(function() {
    /* everything succeeded, move forward */
}, function() {
    /* catch any failure by any of the promises */
});
```

Comment: why would I return promise 2

Comment: This is async code we are talking about.  You may push something to server1, then update the database, then write something to a file, and finally move on with your app.  If any of those async operations fail, you only have to write one fail handler.  **Edit:** It's also a neat feature of promises that if you return a new promise, that becomes the "new" promise (for lack of a better way to describe it).

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly well versed with promises, it's just someone asked me a question about them and I felt like I've worked with a library where if you omit the handler for the fail case on a then, it will call the first argument with an error attached to the response, but when I'm reading A+ spec i interpret that it should behave the other way.   Basically I was hoping to just get a definitive answer about that from here, without having to write a test script